# How to group by a column but use apply on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to run a function on some data grouped according to their **Category** column. But, I have to run the function called **runWordAug** using apply on the other column called **Query**. How do I achieve this? Code I have as of now:

```
import nlpaug.augmenter.word as naw
augWord = naw.ContextualWordEmbsAug()
def runWordAug(doc):
  doc = augWord.augment(doc)
  return doc

dct1 = {}
dct1['Word Aug'] = []
dct1['Category'] = []

import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.read_csv('DataFile.csv')

total_count = 116
z = 0
for i in count_of_word:
  dct1['Sentence Aug'].append(df2.groupby('Category').apply(runWordAug))
  dct1['Category'].append(df2['Category'])
  print(f'Remaining word augment = {total_count-z}')
  z+=1
print(dct1)
```

But this code is running on the Category column (obviously), how do I make it run for the Query column. I think there is a lambda or df.loc way to do it but unable to figure it out.

Comment: Could you share sample Input/Output?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
df2.groupby('Category')['Query'].apply(runWordAug)
```

Comment: Although it does not give an error, it doesn't seem to work as well.